# How to Make guava cache value permanent

Tags: java, caching, guava

Is it possible, using Google Guava's Cache, to keep my cached value in the cache permanently?

Below is how I build my cache:

```
cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()               
                .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .maximumSize(100)
                .build(....);
```

I want my cache to keep the value permanently (currently it's 60 minutes). Is there any method of doing so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just remove `expireAfterWrite` from builder (it's optional feature):

```
cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(100)
            .build(....);
```

so that entries will be evicted only when maximumSize is reached.

Guava's Cache is [well documented](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) but you should probably read [Wiki page](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) too.

P.S. If by "permanent" you meant "will be there after restart", Guava Cache isn't for you since it's in-memory cache.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the value in builder:

```
cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()               
            .expireAfterWrite(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .maximumSize(Long.MAX_VALUE)
            .build(....);
```

Comment: Thanks Vakh.... I just dnt have enough reputation to lift your answer... Its a solution too....

Comment: The other one is definitely better :) I just leave it as a general way of "hacking" time limits.